# How to define two variables with one-to-one relationship in a loop in Shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, for-loop, awk

I have a file whose 3rd column is

```
ifile.txt
2
1
4
3
5
```

I need to assign these values in a loop with one-to-one relationship. i.e.

```
for i in 20 45 50 68 90; do
if [ $i == 20 ]; then j=$(awk 'NR==1 {print $3}' ifile.txt)
if [ $i == 45 ]; then j=$(awk 'NR==2 {print $3}' ifile.txt)
if [ $i == 50 ]; then j=$(awk 'NR==3 {print $3}' ifile.txt)
if [ $i == 68 ]; then j=$(awk 'NR==4 {print $3}' ifile.txt)
if [ $i == 90 ]; then j=$(awk 'NR==5 {print $3}' ifile.txt)
fi
```

Can anybody suggest me a simpler way to do it.

Comment: What do you need to do with these values once you've extracted them from the file? You seem to need them one at a time in the rest of the loop body? Is that true? What does the rest of the loop body look like? Do the `20`, `45`, etc. values appear in `ifile.txt` or does the `20`->`1`, `45`->`2`, etc. mapping exist only in the script/loop?

Comment: Yes, That's true. I need two values one at a time. And there are many executions before and after of this loop also. j value will be used in my next execution and i value will be used as a part of filename for identity of that excution.

Comment: I didn't understand that. Can you show a representative sample of the actual input file and the actual loop that needs to use the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've sometimes used a technique like this:

```
for code in 20/1 45/2 50/3 68/4 90/5
do
    i=${code%/*}
    j=$(awk -v line=${code#*/} 'NR == line { print $3 }' ifile.txt)
    # …use $i and $j…
    echo "i = $i, j = $j"
done
```

This works for erratic orders or gaps etc.  In this case, the `if` code has the indexes going from 1 to 5, so an array would also work:

```
array=('' 20 45 50 68 90)  # Indexing from zero
for line in $(seq 1 $((${#array[@]}-1)) )
do
    i=${array[$line]}
    j=$(awk -v line=$line 'NR == line { print $3 }' ifile.txt)
    # …use $i and $j…
    echo "i = $i, j = $j"
done
```

Given data file `ifile.txt`:

```
A B 2
A B 1
A B 4
A B 3
A B 5
```

Both the scripts shown produce:

```
i = 20, j = 2
i = 45, j = 1
i = 50, j = 4
i = 68, j = 3
i = 90, j = 5
```